# How to mock NativeModules in react-native project by js side?

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs, metro-bundler

I am working on **runnning my react-native app with expo**, the problem I am facing is to mock the NativeModules exported by "react-native", my current solution is using **babel-plugin-module-resolver** plugin to redirect the "react-native" module to my "react-native-proxy" module, which exports a proxy object that expanding NativeModules.

Everything goes well untill I want to use **expo-file-system** to mock our native FileSystem api, **expo-file-system** is an es module, an error look like caused by module mixed use occured. I tried `import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';` in babe.config.js, "react-native-proxy" module, metro.config.js, both throwed an error.

How could I require an es module in babel.config.js or babel-plugin?
Or any idea of achieving the target mentioned above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
As I know that, the NativeModules object exported from "react-native" is created in [Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js), so I change my mock target to this file. I create a file name "NativeModulesProxy.js" which content copied from "Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js", then use `babel-plugin-module-resolver` plugin to redirect the src file to this one.

```
// babel.config.js

const resolvePath = require('babel-plugin-module-resolver').resolvePath;
const path = require('path');
...
plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile, opts) {
            if (sourcePath.includes('NativeModules')) {
              const sourceAbsolutePath = path.resolve(path.dirname(currentFile), sourcePath);
              if (sourceAbsolutePath.endsWith('node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules')) {
                return path.resolve(__dirname, 'NativeModulesProxy');
              }
            }
            return resolvePath(sourcePath, currentFile, opts);
          }
        }
      ]
],
...
```

[NativeModules object](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js#L177) is a quote of global.nativeModuleProxy, base on this, I could create my own proxy object like "global.myNativeModuleProxy" which combines global.nativeModuleProxy and my mock native modules.